# i want to show local places first on google map autocomplete textview

Tags: android

i used autotextcomplete text view for search any place on google map. But it show out of country places first than my place or i have to type almost full name of place. i want to filter local place first after that other places according to my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this following code to filter places as per the country.

```
AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)
                .setCountry("NP") // NP for Nepal, US for USA, CA for Canada, JP for JAPAN, etc
                .build();
autocompleteFragment.setFilter(autocompleteFilter);
```

Comment: is there a method to force local results to list first?  As an example, if my user is in Tampa to force returned results that match Tampa first...then list by geographic distance after that...Orlando, then Atlanta, etc  As of right now, my user starts entering an address or name its pulling matches from across the country first versus showing local matches first.  User has to keep tying to eventually get to local matches.

Answer (score 0):

First set the Filter like this:

```
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder(). setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY).setCountry("US").build();
```

Now pass the filter to the Intent:

```
PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN) .setFilter(typeFilter) .build(this);
```

Comment: This is not an optimal solution to the question asked. Still missing that how an Indian person see "Uthrakhand" if type UK and not "United Kingdom" as first option, and the complete reverse if a guy in london searches the same keyword.